# Moving Average for RSS BLE array value

Tags: javascript, rss, bluetooth-lowenergy, moving-average

I would like to implement the moving average algorithm for the BLE RSS array value based on the output below. The window period is 10 for RSS value such that;

B1 (Beacon 1) will calculate for the first 10 value of RSS. Then, it will compute the next 10 value and excluding the first RSS value. Next, it will average the RSS by excluding the first two value of RSS. The same goes for other Beacon as well (up to 4 beacons). Does anyone know how to do that

```
                    TextView.setText("Major:" + b.getMajor() + "Minor:" + b.getMinor() + " RSS:" + b.getRssi());
                    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(BeaconRssWrtId.get("1")));
                    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(BeaconRssWrtId.get("2")));
                    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(BeaconRssWrtId.get("3")));
                    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(BeaconRssWrtId.get("4")));
```

Output

D/test: [-88.0, -85.0, -85.0, -84.0, -84.0, -84.0, -81.0, -81.0, -84.0, -84.0, -85.0, -85.0, -87.0, -87.0, -87.0, -86.0, -86.0, -84.0, -84.0, -84.0, -82.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -86.0, -86.0, -82.0, -82.0, -82.0, -82.0, -83.0, -78.0, -80.0, -84.0, -80.0, -79.0, -77.0, -76.0, -74.0, -78.0, -80.0, -80.0, -81.0, -81.0, -83.0, -84.0, -86.0, -87.0, -84.0, -83.0, -82.0, -86.0, -87.0, -84.0, -86.0, -89.0, -85.0, -85.0, -80.0, -79.0, -79.0, -79.0, -88.0, -85.0, -82.0, -86.0, -86.0, -84.0, -85.0, -85.0, -89.0, -86.0, -86.0, -82.0, -82.0, -79.0, -81.0, -82.0, -83.0, -83.0, -81.0, -81.0, -81.0, -79.0, -76.0, -83.0, -82.0, -80.0, -80.0, -82.0, -86.0, -89.0, -90.0, -90.0, -90.0, -88.0, -81.0, -80.0, -82.0, -82.0, -82.0, -81.0, -82.0, -79.0, -84.0, -78.0, -78.0, -78.0, -82.0, -79.0, -81.0, -83.0, -85.0, -81.0, -78.0, -78.0, -80.0, -80.0, -80.0, -80.0, -80.0, -85.0, -81.0, -82.0, -84.0, -83.0, -83.0, -83.0, -83.0, -89.0, -89.0, -86.0, -86.0, -86.0, -86.0, -87.0, -87.0, -85.0, -85.0, -83.0, -85.0, -84.0]
D/test: [-98.0, -98.0, -94.0, -95.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -96.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -101.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0, -100.0]
D/test: [-101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -101.0, -100.0, -102.0, -102.0, -102.0, -101.0]
D/test: [-105.0, -105.0, -105.0, -105.0, -105.0, -105.0, -106.0, -106.0, -106.0, -106.0, -106.0, -106.0, -106.0, -106.0, -105.0, -105.0, -105.0, -105.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -101.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -99.0, -104.0, -102.0, -102.0, -102.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -103.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0, -104.0]
Process 4370 terminated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mean = array => array.reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0) / array.length;
const movingAverage = (array, period) => array.map((v, i) => i < period -1 ? undefined : mean(array.slice(i - period + 1, i + 1)));
console.log(movingAverage([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3)) // [undefined, undefined, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```